# Multiple Datasource-Files in one EAR

Tags: jboss, datasource, jca

I'm testing the [sapbabijca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sapbapijcaadapt/) for jboss 6. Currently i have 2 -ds.xml files in my ear. One is for my jdbc connection, the other contains the config of my sap connector. Now, when i try to deploy my ear i get:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching files not allowed: ["/C:/Users/abaetz/workspaces/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_final_Server1295446459986/deploy/AdvancedTracking.ear/META-INF/sap-bw-ds.xml", "/C:/Users/abaetz/workspaces/JBossWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_final_Server1295446459986/deploy/AdvancedTracking.ear/META-INF/VersionTracker-ds.xml"]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.handleMultipleFiles(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:440) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:319) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:376) [:2.2.0.GA]`
```

I can't merge the two files, because they are based on different xml-schemas.
How can i get my ear to work?

Greetings,
Laures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "different schemas"?

The -ds.xml file has a fixed format, that both definitions should adhere to.
And within a -ds.xml file it is posible to define multiple data sources or managed connections.

Comment: according to the [jboss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss.html) there there is one format for jdbc connections and one for jca adaptors. I require both.

Comment: Ewww you are right. As the -ds.xml files are internally transformed into -service.xml files, as fallback / workaround could be to rewrite the definitions in a -service.xml file that contains all the needed MBeans.